# Populate Combo box with JSON file, ExtJs 4.x.x

Tags: json, extjs, combobox, populate

```
 Ext.define('Form', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name:'type', type:'String'}
    ]
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    model: 'Form',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {

        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/test.json',
        reader: {
            type : 'json',
            root: 'types'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('DForms', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    bodyPadding: 12,
    layout : 'auto',
    autoScroll : true,

        items: [{
            xtype:'selectcombo',
            queryMode:'local',
            emptyText: 'Select Condition',
            store:store,
            displayField: 'type',
            valueField: 'type',
            width : 200,
            typeAhead : true
        }],
});
```

When this loads, the selectcombo is empty, nothing gets loaded, i have searched through many sites, and can't find anything to help. Any suggestions would be great

Comment: Give json file contents.It will help to find issue

Answer (score 0):

The `xtype` you look for is `combo`, the `store` type is `JsonStore` because the `ArrayStore` will not interpret the `json` from the `types` root as you might expect. I can not simulate the `ajax` request here though.

```js
Ext.onReady(function() {

  Ext.define('Form', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
      name: 'type',
      type: 'String'
    }]
  });

  var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Form',
    data: [{
      type: 'Aaaaaaa'
    }, {
      type: 'Bbbbbb'
    }, {
      type: 'Ccccccccccc'
    }, {
      type: 'Ddddddd'
    }]

  });

  Ext.define('DForms', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    bodyPadding: 12,
    layout: 'auto',
    autoScroll: true,
    items: [{
      xtype: 'combo',
      queryMode: 'local',
      emptyText: 'Select Condition',
      store: store,
      displayField: 'type',
      valueField: 'type',
      width: 200,
      typeAhead: true
    }],
  });

  Ext.create('DForms', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/4.2.1/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
```

Comment: it doesn't let me

Answer (score 0):

I think type in fields is case-sensitive. So try

```
fields :[{name : 'type', type : 'string'}]
```

If still not working, as Tejas1991 pointed out check the content of your json.

Comment: yes, in combination with yours and bluehipy, it worked :)